# Json use Jq to parse, read and return true if enrty found

Tags: jq

Apologies if this is basic but the doc for jq is not so good
i have this json:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": [{
        "hostid": "10084",
        "host": "Zabbix server",
        "interfaces": [{
            "interfaceid": "1",
            "ip": "127.0.0.1"
        }]
    }, {
        "hostid": "10336",
        "host": "AUTO",
        "interfaces": [{
            "interfaceid": "4",
            "ip": "1.2.3.4"
        }]
    }, {
        "hostid": "10337",
        "host": "AUTOSERVER",
        "interfaces": [{
            "interfaceid": "5",
            "ip": "4.5.6.7"
        }]
    }, {
        "hostid": "10348",
        "host": "Server00001",
        "interfaces": [{
            "interfaceid": "16",
            "ip": "4.5.6.7"
        }]
    
    }],
    "id": 2
}
```

i need to find a way to use jq to find if "Server0001" exists in one of the hosts
i know i can use grep but i prefer using jq here, like select..
any help or ref toa good doc would be much appriciated

Comment: What should be your output?

Comment: true / false. but the point is im not sure how to use jq on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`any` (see the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#any%2Cany%28condition%29%2Cany%28generator%3Bcondition%29)) can return a boolean value if a condition matches with at least one item.

```sh
jq 'any(.result[]; .host == "Server0001")'
```

```json
false
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/GJ3KiTMMFz)

```sh
jq 'any(.result[]; .host == "Server00001")'
```

```json
true
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Gnx9FJyKRF)

---

You may also want to use the some parameters when invoking `jq` (see the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq)): The `--arg`  option, for instance, lets you add a variable which can be initialized from outside the filter string. And with the `-e` (or `--exit-status`) flag  you can have `jq` set the exit status according to the filter's final result. Together, this enables you to use `jq` like this:

```sh
if jq --arg host "Server0001" -e 'any(.result[]; .host == $host)';
then
  …
else
  …
fi
```

Comment: You may also want to use `-e` so that the exit status of `jq` reflects the boolean value of the filter, so that you don't need to capture the standard output and compare it to the string `true`.

Comment: @chepner Was just about to add it. Thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: Thank you! very much appriciated!